# get parent div id by using image src inside that div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am having a parent `div` say `div_parent` with 4 div elements say `div1`, `div2`, `div3` and `div4` and 1 button `add image`.

When I click `add image` button, it adds 2 images to all div.

Now I have 1 image with src say `1.png` which is inside one of these 4 divs.
So my question is that by just src (1.png) how can i get its parent div id?

I have tried following code

```
$('#div_parent > div > img').map(function() {
  if (($(this).attr('src')) == '1.png')
    xx = $(this).attr('id');
  p = xx.parent();
});
alert("--" + xx + "---" + p.attr('id'));
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code

Comment: maybe change `xx.parent()` to `$(this).parent()`

Comment: A side note: You know that the `p = xx.parent();` will be executed even if `($(this).attr('src')) == '1.png'` is not true because you do not have curly braces for the if clause?

Comment: @t.niese mmh no that's not what happens. If no curly braces are found, the first statement found after the if - and before a semicolon; is what is executed if conditional is true. So if semicolon is right afther the if brace, nothing executed, or else it will run the first statement after the if. BUT... It's good practice, if you don't use curly braces, to **write the statement to execute in the same line as the if**

Comment: @FabioLolli my point was not about the  the first statement after the `if` which is  `xx = $(this).attr('id')`, but about the `p = xx.parent()` which is after that statement. Bedside the fact that the `xx.parent()`  wouldn't make sense in that case because `xx` is  string, it would not make sense to look for the parent of `xx` if the `if condition` is false. It looks more like if the `p = xx.parent()` should have been together with the `xx = $(this).attr('id')` in curly braces.

Comment: @t.niese oh yeah sorry, just realized I was talking about the wrong line :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more way you can do it

```
var id = $('#div_parent').find('img[src="1.png"]') 
   .closest('div')
   .attr('id')
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot , its working , saved my lots of time :-)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without a `map` using the [Attribute Equals Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/).

```
var id = $('#div_parent > div > img[src="1.png"]') // get the image with the source '1.png'
           .closest('div') // get the closest ancestor with the tag name div
           .attr('id') // get the id of that div
```

Comment: It is also helpful for my question. :-)